# Need to Load Hidden Button at Certain Moment

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a static html page with JS code

Code:

```js
<script>
var questions = [
  {question:"What's your first name?"},
  {question:"What's your last name?"},
  {question:"What's your email?", pattern: /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/},
  {question:"Create your password", type: "password"},
  {question:"Retype your password", type: "password"}
]

/*
  do something after the questions have been answered
  
*/
var onComplete = function() {

    var h1 = document.createElement('h1')
    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Thanks ' + questions[0].answer + ' for your registration!'))
    setTimeout(function() {
      register.parentElement.appendChild(h1)
      setTimeout(function() { h1.style.opacity = 1 }, 50)
    }, 1000)

}

;(function(questions, onComplete) {

    var tTime = 100 // transition transform time from #register in ms
    var wTime = 200 // transition width time from #register in ms
    var eTime = 1000 // transition width time from inputLabel in ms

    // init
    // --------------
    if (questions.length == 0) return

    var position = 0

    putQuestion()

    forwardButton.addEventListener('click', validate)
    inputField.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        transform(0, 0) // ie hack to redraw
        if (e.keyCode == 13) validate()
    })

    previousButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (position === 0) return
        position -= 1
        hideCurrent(putQuestion)
    })


    // functions
    // --------------

    // load the next question
    function putQuestion() {
        inputLabel.innerHTML = questions[position].question
        inputField.type = questions[position].type || 'text'
        inputField.value = questions[position].answer || ''
        inputField.focus()

        // set the progress of the background
        progress.style.width = position * 100 / questions.length + '%'

        previousButton.className = position ? 'ion-android-arrow-back' : 'ion-person'

        showCurrent()

    }

    // when submitting the current question
    function validate() {

        var validateCore = function() {      
          return inputField.value.match(questions[position].pattern || /.+/)
        }

        if (!questions[position].validate) questions[position].validate = validateCore

        // check if the pattern matches
        if (!questions[position].validate()) wrong(inputField.focus.bind(inputField))
        else ok(function() {

            // execute the custom end function or the default value set
            if (questions[position].done) questions[position].done()
            else questions[position].answer = inputField.value

            ++position

            // if there is a new question, hide current and load next
            if (questions[position]) hideCurrent(putQuestion)
            else hideCurrent(function() {
                // remove the box if there is no next question
                register.className = 'close'
                progress.style.width = '100%'

                onComplete()
              
            })

        })

    }
    
    </script>
```

```css
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #fbc02d;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .8s ease-in-out;
}

#progress {
  position: absolute;
  background: #c49000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.center {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


#register {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transition: transform .1s ease-in-out;
}

#register.close {
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: .8s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

#forwardButton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fbc02d;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 20
}
#previousButton {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 30px; /* same as padding on container */
  top: 12px;
  z-index: 20;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#previousButton:hover {color: #c49000}
#forwardButton:hover {color: #c49000}
.wrong #forwardButton {color: #ff2d26}
.close #forwardButton, .close #previousButton {color: #fff}

#inputContainer {
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin: 10px 60px 10px 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

#inputContainer input {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

#inputLabel {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 32px; /* same as container padding + margin */
  left: 20px; /* same as container padding */
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}

#inputContainer input:valid + #inputLabel {
  top: 6px;
  left: 42px; /* space for previous arrow */
  margin-left: 0!important;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}

#inputProgress {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fbc02d;
  width: 0;
  transition: width .6s ease-in-out;
}

.wrong #inputProgress {
  border-color: #ff2d26;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  #forwardButton {right: 10px}
  #previousButton {left: 10px}
  #inputLabel {left: 0}
  #inputContainer {padding-left: 0; margin-right:20px}
}

</style>
```

```html
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<div id="progress"></div>

<div class="center">
  <div id="register"> 
    
    <i id="previousButton" class="ion-android-arrow-back"></i> 
    <i id="forwardButton" class="ion-android-arrow-forward"></i>
    
    <div id="inputContainer">
      <input id="inputField" required multiple />
      <label id="inputLabel"></label>
      <div id="inputProgress"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Registry form page that loads text message at the end. From there I need a button to be loaded below the text. Button that previously was hidden.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: JS code is end process on my page.
User will fill a form, text message will load, and everything ends there.

I would like to load a button (there is no button code here, as I don't know how exactly I should do it)

Button should be loaded below the text, right after the text is loaded.
So user can proceed to another page.

I got some answers, thanks for helping me.
I am not good at coding, and I am not sure how exactly to call it,

so I would appreciate if you could drop me a html code too with button ID

Purpose is to preview button below that text with on click function to a external URL.

Much thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the problem?

Comment: Yes mate, this js code is end of my script.
Result is: user fill a form, and text message appears (end of everything)

I need to add a button to show from here, at the end, so user can click it and proceed to another page.

Comment: @DDnnA what is register in you code and seems like you snippet doesnt make - please make just code formatting , do you need to show continue button after user fill up the form ?

Comment: Hello, I have updated the code. This is what I have, I hope it gives you a better view.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question and make more unnecessary moderation work for the site members

Answer (score 1):

You are showing h1 element

```
h1.style.opacity = 1
```

Not a button

Edit:

```
var onComplete = function() {

    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('text ' + questions[0].answer + ' text!'));

    var btn = document.createElement("button");
     btn.onclick = function(){
         document.location("link_to_the_next_page");
     }
     h1.appendChild(btn);

    setTimeout(function() {
      register.parentElement.appendChild(h1);
      setTimeout(function() { h1.style.opacity = 1 }, 50);
    }, 1000);

}
```

Edit: don't you missing `semi colons` ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, yes this js code is end of process on my page. There is a form, user fill it, and text appears = end of everything. I want to add a button below the text, to show right after text is loaded, so user can click it and proceed to another page.

Comment: I would also need anything that goes along this, such button ID <div> for html part, or what it takes. Sorry for speaking like this, but I am very weak with coding and I also don't understand the term semi colons. I hope that you might be able to help me with this. Thank you for trying.

Comment: 1. Just add `btn.id = "your_id"`. 2.End of each line, you must type `;`

Comment: I have updated the entire code with no edits, pls check it. I try your thing but got a tiny button without functionality. Could you give me the exact one from watching the entire code, I should put it from the start.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var onComplete = function() {
    var btn=document.createElement('button');
    btn.type='button';
    btn.id='btnProceed';
    btn.innerText='Proceed';
    btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        // do something
    },false);

    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.innerText=`text ${questions[0].answer} text!`;
    h1.appendChild(btn);

    setTimeout(function() {
      register.parentElement.appendChild(h1);
      setTimeout(function() { h1.style.opacity = 1 }, 50);
    }, 1000);
}
```

And then you can use the ID of that button to catch the click and redirect to the next page.

Comment: Yup, but I am a complete newbie and I wrote something regarding ID and it won't work. My error must be. If you can, please drop me the ID code too, and thank you very much for assisting me.

Comment: I have updated the code. If you can, please take a look at it now.

Comment: @DDnnA Sorry for the waiting, I updated my code and about the other button where it's `forwardButton.addEventListener('click', validate)` you have to declare the variable `forwardButton` by using `var forwardButton=document.querySelector('#forwardButton');` before.